# Calculate sales difference of last year and current year in pyspark df

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aggregate-functions

I have df with following column:-

```
"sdan8","sdan8_name","sdshan","sdshan_name","sdrcd","shtkby","shurrf","shurrf_udc","shir01","schnl","schnl_ecom","bu_schnl","bu_schnl_name","sdkcoo_name","bu_ac20","bu_co","aiac03","aiac03_udc","sdlitm","aiac23","aiac23_udc","sditm","sdvend","sdvend_name","gl_year","gl_month")."_prc_net_cost","_prc_net_sales","sdsoqs","sduprc","sdaexp","sduncs","sdecst","aluprc_bonus","aluprc_cost"
```

From here I need to create two table:- 1.diff_sales_cur_prev and 2. diff_sales_cur_prev.
1st column will calculate _prc_net_sales difference between current_year and current_year-1 in rest it will be 0.
2nd column will calculate prc_net_sales-1 difference between current_year and current_year-2 in rest it will be 0.

How can I calculate it?
I tried following:-

```
partition_by=Window.partitionBy('sdan8', 'sdan8_name', 'sdshan', 'sdshan_name', 'sdrcd','shtkby', 'shurrf', 'shurrf_udc', 'shir01',
                                'schnl', 'schnl_ecom', 'bu_schnl', 'bu_schnl_name', 'bu_ac20', 'bu_co', 'aiac03', 'aiac03_udc', 'sdlitm',
                                'aiac23', 'aiac23_udc', 'sditm', 'sdvend', 'sdvend_name', 'gl_year', 'gl_month', 'i1$dssb', 'i1$dssu', 'imsrp1',
                                'imsrp2', 'imsrp5', 'imsrp6', 'imdsc1', 'imdsc2').orderBy(f.col("gl_year"),f.col("gl_month"))
df = df.withColumn(
        "_dif_sales_cur_prev",
        f.sum(
            f.when(
                f.col("gl_year") == current_year,
                f.col("_prc_net_sales")
            ).otherwise(lit(0))
        ).over(partition_by)-f.sum(
            f.when(
                f.col("gl_year")==current_year-1,
                f.col("_prc_net_sales")
                ).otherwise(lit(0))
        ).over(partition_by)
    )

df = df.withColumn(
    "_dif_sales_cur_prev_prec",
    
    f.sum(
        f.when(
            f.col("gl_year") == current_year-1,
            f.col("_prc_net_sales")
        ).otherwise(lit(0))
    ).over(partition_by)-f.sum(
        f.when(
            f.col("gl_year")==current_year-2,
            f.col("_prc_net_sales")
            ).otherwise(lit(0))
    ).over(partition_by)
)
```

But it didn't work. How can i get desired result.

here is sample output:-
[image]

Comment: Can you include a dummy required output? Also when you two tables with 1st and 2nd column what do you mean? You need two different tables with one column each or a single table with two columns?

Comment: @AlefiyaAbbas, I have added image as sample output. Do you need more explanation?

Comment: @ArpanGhimire are you sure your sample output is correct ? first line should be `2023 1 13 13 10 3 8 ...` ? no ?